# Spring MVC Map Multiple Dynamic Form Elements with same name while value contains comma

Tags: java, html, spring, post

I know how to map form elements with the same `name` attribute into corresponding array `RequestParam` parameters. I am using this technique for a while. Now i ran into a problem when one of these values contain **COMMA** character.

For example code below represents my html page:

```
<input type="text" name="controlValue" id="controlValue1" />
<input type="text" name="controlValue" id="controlValue2" />
<input type="text" name="controlValue" id="controlValue3" />
```

Now in my controller i have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@RequestParam("controlValue") String[] controlValue) {
    // doSomething and return
}
```

Everything works ok if i post values not containing COMMA characters. But when i type some values with COMMA character in `controlValue` textboxes then my array contains wrong values. Is there a way to setup delimiter character for same name form elements or is there another solution? Thanks...